# No kernel header files in `5.10.0-rc1-sev-es+`, despite installing `linux-headers-`uname -r`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, linux-device-driver, linux-kernel-headers

I am running a Debian 9 at kernel version `5.10.0-rc1-sev-es+`. The directory `/lib/modules/5.10.0-rc1-sev-es+/build` (which I need for compiling kernel modules) does not seem to exists. However, when I run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` it simply tells me:
`linux-headers-5.10.0-rc1-sev-es is already the newest version (5.10.0-rc1-sev-es-1).`. Searching for the package also does not show the header files for `5.10.0-rc1-sev-es+`:

```
sudo apt-cache search linux-headers-5.
linux-headers-5.2.0+ - Linux kernel headers for 5.2.0+ on amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-rc1-sev-es - Linux kernel headers for 5.10.0-rc1-sev-es on amd64
linux-headers-5.1.0+ - Linux kernel headers for 5.1.0+ on amd64
```

Comment: If you run `lsmod`, then pick a module at random and do `modinfo` on it, what does the `filename` part at the top say?  Also, does `ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)` have anything in it?  Or is it empty?

Comment: By the way, if you do a `dpkg -L linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, that should tell you where the headers got installed to.  It may be somewhere like `/usr/src`.

Comment: Those package names are not from the standard Debian repositories. Did whatever build the linux-image-*xxx* package also build the corresponding linux-headers-*xxx* package?